# Visual Studio HTML designer adds a <p></p> every time I switch to design view, I end up with a gazillion lines

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008, text-editor, text-formatting

I use split view, whenever I change the HTML code and switch to design view (clicking that popup "Design view is out of source view blah blah") VS adds 3

lines to the HTML.

eventually it has many many lines which is very annoying to code like this.

Has enyone encountered this before?

Comment: Real coders dont use design view... nah i dont use it usually but I tried to and it didnt happen to me. Are you sure its not something in your options? does it only happen in specific file types?

Comment: Real coders are concentrating in coding, therefore, when it comes to design they prefer not wasting time on writing HTML but rather dragging controls to the page and let the designer lay it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use the design view, but can you post your html code so I could check if its valid?

btw: Do you adhere to the intellisense rules, or do u have your own ways of coding html files?

My view is that your html code is invalid, and design view has problems displaying it and messes it up.

Comment: The reason was I nested Ps which is not allowed (i.e. <p><p></p></p>) or/and a div was placed inside a P which is also not allowed, thanks for your point.